# Rewrite the equation of a conic in cartesian coordinates

Tags: conic-sections, polar-coordinates

> Consider the equation for a conic in polar co-ordinates $(r,\theta)$
>
> $$r = \frac{k}{1 - e\cos(\theta)}    \qquad \qquad    (1)$$
>
> in the case where $k > 0$ and $e > 1$. Show that equation $(1)$ can be re-written in cartesian coordinates $(x, y)$ as
>   $$ \frac{(x-x_0)^2}{a^2} - \frac{y^2}{b^2} = 1     \qquad \qquad   (2)
> $$
>
> where $a^2$, $b^2$ and $x_0$ are functions of $k$ and $e$. What type of conic does equation $(2)$ represent?

Here is my attempt.

Take $$x = r\cos(\theta)$$ and $$y = r\sin(\theta)$$.
Now $r - re\cos(\theta) = k \Longleftrightarrow r = k + r\cos(\theta)$.

Squaring leads to $$r^2 = k^2 + r^2 e^2 \cos^2(\theta) + 2kre\cos(\theta)$$
which implies $$x^2 + y^2 = k^2 +e^2 x^2 + 2kex$$

Since $e>1$ then $e$ does not equal $1$ hence $1-e^2$ does not equal $0$ so we can complete the square for the equation

$$y^2 = k^2 + (e^2 - 1)x^2 + 2kex$$

But I'm not sure what i have to do from here on.

Comment: You didn't complete the square, did you?

Comment: no i'm not sure how to, i know we have to but i can't figure out how